# Does submit button apply to only form its in or all forms on page?

Tags: html, forms, submit, form-submit

I am planning on setting up multiple forms on a page and wanted to make sure that this is ok.  Do submit buttons act only on the form they are inside of or do they apply to all the forms on a page?

Comment: By default I believe it's only the form the button is inside of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submit button submits a form. It seems that the specifications do not clearly say that this means the enclosing `form` element, probably because this was taken as self-evident. And it’s certainly what browsers do.

HTML5 drafts make this a bit clearer by introducing the concept of “[form owner](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/association-of-controls-and-forms.html)” of a field (such as a submit button). By default, the form owner is the enclosing `form` element, though the proposed `form` attribute of a field could change this. And a submit button is defined as submitting the form owner.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (and I'm pretty sure), submit buttons/inputs will by default only act on it's parent form. You can read more about forms in the [W3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#buttons).

So if you just wonder if it's ok to have multiple forms in your page, then yes, it is.